# Intel Smart Sound Technology - No sound - Dummy Ouput

Tags: drivers, audio, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I have bought a new laptop and installed a GNU/Linux distro along with Windows 10, the problem I am having is that I have no audio, the audio does not work with any distro that I tried while on Windows the audio works fine, I would appreciate it a lot if someone can help me to fix the audio.

A little more information about my problem:

> Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS Release: 20.04 Codename: focus

> - headphones don't work either
> - apparently my sound card uses: intel SST (intel smart sound technology)
> - Fast start up of windows is disabled.
> - Output Device is "Dummy Output"
> - Kernel version: 5.15.0-41-generic
> - Output of "aplay -l" is :

```
    card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
    card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
    card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
    card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
    card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

> - Output of "inxi -A" is:

```
    Audio:
      Device-1: Intel Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio 
      driver: snd_hda_intel 
      Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.15.0-41-generic
```

> - Output of "cat /proc/asound/cards" is :

```
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                  HDA Intel PCH at 0xa1218000 irq 130
```

> - Output of "hwinfo --sound" is :

```
 17: PCI 1f.3: 0401 Multimedia audio controller                  
  [Created at pci.386]
  Unique ID: nS1_.0bu6GdcFr73
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:1f.3
  Hardware Class: sound
  Device Name: "Onboard - Sound"
  Model: "Intel Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x9dc8 "Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1c6c 
  SubDevice: pci 0x122a 
  Revision: 0x30
  Driver: "snd_hda_intel"
  Driver Modules: "snd_hda_intel"
  Memory Range: 0xa1218000-0xa121bfff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0xa1000000-0xa10fffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 130 (273 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d00009DC8sv00001C6Csd0000122Abc04sc01i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: snd_hda_intel is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_hda_intel"
  Driver Info #1:
    Driver Status: snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
```

> - Output of "lspci":

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Iris Plus Graphics 655 (rev 01)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Thermal Controller (rev 30)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Controller (rev 30)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Shared SRAM (rev 30)
00:14.5 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation BayHubTech Integrated SD controller (rev 30)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 30)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:15.2 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 9dea (rev 30)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 30)
00:19.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Host Controller (rev 30)
00:1a.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Device 9dc4 (rev 30)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 9da8 (rev 30)
00:1e.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 9dab (rev 30)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SPI Controller (rev 30)
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

**======================[UPDATE]============================**

I installed Fedora 36 Workstation, and installed the latest kernel (5.18...). Now I can hear sound, but I had to set the volume to 153%.[image]

The volume is still too low, but progress is progress. :D

Comment: Try Fedora 36. Make sure you've updated its kernel to 5.18.

Comment: Okay, i will try it.

Comment: I installed Fedora, installed the latest kernel and now it detects my sound device with a new driver, and makes a little sound when I open sound settings, but still no sound, I think it needs some configuration to work.

Comment: Make sure you have no messages about missing firmware in your `dmesg`. IF there are none, please file a bug report here: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Drivers under `Sound(ALSA)` Also check the existing reports: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/buglist.cgi?product=Drivers&component=Sound(ALSA)&resolution=--- - I'm too lazy to do it for you.

Comment: There are already existing reports about Intel Smart Sounds but no idea if and how they've resolved: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213159 https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=212465 https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=208555 There's a LOT to digest.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the support, by the way, I noticed that with fedora, my headphones work fine.

Comment: Good, so at least there's some progress :-)

Comment: Now I realize that the sound actually works, but it's too low to hear. I was able to hear the music coming from my internal audio device by setting the volume to 153%.

The volume is still too low, but at least I hear sound :-)

Comment: Your device looks relatively old and should work out of the box. You seem to have Windows 10 installed on it? Does audio work in it?

Comment: Audio on windows 10 works loud and clear, not sure why it's not the same for fedora but at least the audio works now.

Comment: I highly recommend filing a bug report.

Comment: Okay, i will try that.